# Importing pptx slides into docx document

Tags: python-docx, python-pptx

I have literally hundreds of slides created with python-pptx. Many of these slides have charts I would like to use in a docx file.  So what I would like to do is use python-docx to import these slides/charts into a docx file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not with the current `python-pptx` or `python-docx` APIs.

Such a thing is possible of course, since the Word application will allow you to "paste" charts from PowerPoint and in fact the charts themselves are specified in DrawingML, an XML vocabulary that is shared between PowerPoint, Word, and Excel.

But to make this work with Python, you'd have to dig quite deep into the internals of both `python-pptx` and `python-docx` (although their architectures are much the same). You would probably also need to learn more about the respective XML vocabularies than you really wanted to know. So you might want to consider alternate approaches such as using `win32com` support for this sort of thing, especially if you are running on Windows and this is a one-time job and does not need to be hosted on a server for ongoing use.

If you thought you *did* want to tackle it, a good first step might be to inspect the XML related to a PowerPoint chart (located in both the slide and the chart-parts of the PPTX package) and also inspect the corresponding XML that appears in a Word (.docx) file that includes a chart. That will give you an idea of what needs to come over from the PPTX package, what transformations it may need to undergo (namespace changes perhaps) and where it would need to be added into the DOCX package, including updating relationship files and perhaps updating certain ID values to make them unique in the target package.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It looks like I should go the 'win32com' route, although I'm running in Mac OS X and this will be an on-going need. Is there anything else I should consider before I dive into 'win32com'?

Comment: win32com is only going to work on a Windows machine (or VM).